# My application always crashes in sqlite3utf8CharLen

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm developing an application using SQLite3. My application always crashes in sqlite3utf8CharLen and I have no idea why. The name of the function suggests that the problem might be related to character encodings. sqlite3utf8CharLen takes two parameters, const char* z and int nByte. The values of arguments when sqlite3utf8CharLen crashes are:

```
z=
"TPCAGSUBCFG2(
                    AGID                REAL,       -- ID des Haupt-AG
                    LINIE               REAL,       -- Linie auf der dieser AG laeuft
                    SUBAGID         REAL,       -- ID des Subs, hat ein AG keine Subs, dann hier die Id des AG selbst                       
                    SKALERTDIST REAL,       -- Distanz, ab der auf ein SK Ereignis hingewiesen wird 
                    SKALERTTIME REAL,       -- Zeit, die vergehen muss, bis für dieses Ereignis wieder ein Sound gespielt wird
                    SKALERTSND  TEXT)"

nByte=426
```

There's a german umlaut in the string. Might this related to the problem?

Since I have no clue where the problem might be rooted, I'll give some contextual information: I'm developing on Windows. I make heavy use of STL and I'm using std::wstring throughout the project.

Comment: What is the top-level SQLite function in the stack trace?

Comment: Show your code that calls this function.

Comment: That's a little bit difficult. I'll try to provdide the code. But it'll take some time. In the meanwhile, can you tell, what you're up to? Any clue?

Comment: Some parameter is wrong, either the database or the statement or the string.